# What do these screen mean black background yellow or blue with date and time?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5, lineageos, system-freeze, date-and-time, smart-cover

Some times my phone gets stuck at this screen. I can take a screen shot but it is otherwise unresponsive. What does this screen mean. It's usually yellow or blue with the time.

[image: blue]
[image: yellow]

I want to think if I can take a screen shoot, I can otherwise recover from them. But each time I get it I have to restart the phone. I got these with Lineage 14.1, and now I'm getting them with 15.1 too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe it is the flip cover, due to faulty hall sensor. Disable in settings (after reboot) seems to be the answer. According to [this post](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s5/help/s5-hangs-blue-screen-flashing-to-t3621211), the setting can be disabled by going

- Settings
- Connected Devices
- Smart cover
- Off