# Samsung A50's navigation bar hidden when it is inside a case

Tags: samsung, navigation-bar, smart-cover

I apologize if this is a dumb question. I don't actually own an Android phone, just asking for a family member.

The navigation bar in a Samsung A50 disappears when the phone is inside a wallet-type case. The only way I found to make it reappear, is by removing the phone from the case.

It seems there is a magnet that triggers the navigation bar to be hidden. The owner of the phone told me that this started happening when she updated the OS. I don't have version information at this moment, but will add the info as soon as I get it from the phone owner.

Thank you!

Comment: "*[...] inside a wallet-type case*", "*It seems there is a magnet [...]*" this looks like a "smart cover" which may change the device behavior, like [showing a simpler user interface](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/199653/44325) when the cover is closed.